# Take an entire branch and rebase it on another commit

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-rebase

I recently inherited some PHP code that was a mess. It had harcoded paths and URLs all over the place, which I had to change every time I move the code from my test server to the production server. I ended up  creating a new "production" branch separated from the "master" one, where I changed all the hardcoded paths and URLS to the ones used in the production server. In other words:

```
A - B - C
        \
         \-D - E
```

`C` is the master branch where I work. In it, the URLs and paths correspond to my test server. I created a new "production" branch (`D` and `E`), where I changed the paths to the production server.

Now I have added some new features to the master branch:

```
A - B - C - F - G - H
        \
         \-D - E
```

And I want to apply those `D` and `E` commits where I changed the paths and URLs to the latest changes, to `H`.

From what I read, `rebase` seems like the exact feature for this, but:

1. The docs I read suggest that it's a bad idea to rebase branches that have already been pushed to the remote server, which is exactly what I've done.
2. In my case, the "production" branch has two commits (because there were so many paths to change that I forgot some of them at first), so I don't know exactly if I can take all of them and rebase them entirely.

I am using Sourcetree on Windows and Mac, although I can handle the command line too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git rebase` in this case. There could be chances that some code conflicts can occur, but those can be solved manually, provided the conflicting files are textual files - code files, json files, etc.

Used it plenty of times, and if used rightly, no issues occur and the child branches can be then merged easily into main branch.

As a rule-of-thumb for me, I squash commits on the child branch into one commit using `git rebase -i HEAD~<no.of.commits.to.be.squashed>`, so then if any rebase conflicts occur, I can resolve them for one commit only.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is to have a branch for each possible value combinations that you might have. This means that whenever some new attribute is added, you will always need to have as many commits as the number of branches. Also, when you change a value, you will also need to apply that on as many copies as you have. Finally, you might have some secret values which should not be versioned, such as passwords, API secrets etc.

Instead of the insecure and superfluous approach that you have chosen, an alternative and arguably better way to solve your problem is the following:

## 1. Create an env file where you set all the values of the settings in your local

Create .env.php and set all the values to your local

## 2. Add .env.php to .gitignore

We don't want to version .env.php, because it is volatile and it may contain secrets that should not be versioned

## 3. Change all references to these settings

Go through your code and replace all the hard-coded URLs and whatnot to these settings.

## 4. Copy env.php to all copies of the repository

After you copied this file to all copies of the repository, change the actual values that should be used there

## 5. Sync

Pull the changes on all your branches or merge them into these branches, so the settings will be dynamically inferred based on .env.php

## 6. You may want to have multiple unversioned configurations

## Conclusion

Instead of replicating all your branches to as many branches as you have, make sure that you infer them dynamically and you have an unversioned copy of .env.php with those values. At the first instance, you could implement this function into .env.php:

```
function env() {
    return [
        "key1" => "value1",
        "key2" => "value2",
        //...
    ];
}
```

and include or require this file so, instead of URL1 you would do something like `env()["URL1"]`

Comment: In case of any confusion, the phrase "env file" is often used to refer to a specific file, intended to emulate in development settings that come from an external source in production (e.g. in container-based systems). The "env file" in this case is just "a settings file", and could be named whatever you like, and in whatever format you like. "env.php" isn't a _bad_ name, I just wanted to clarify that distinction.

Comment: @IMSoP thanks for the clarification, yes, indeed, this is an unversioned file that needs to be present in every copy of the repo, customized with the settings that need with the values desirable there.

Comment: Oh, I'm definitely planning to rewrite everything properly. The problem is that the client is demanding some features to be added ASAP, so for now I've had to work with what I have.

Comment: @PaulJ think this through. How much time does it take to collect all the values of all combinations and to create separate .env.php files for them? How long does it take to add a line to .gitignore and commit it? How long does it take to find & replace all uses of these settings? And then how long does it take to copy the right .env.php to each copy of the repo and pull or merge or cherry pick? It is up to you to estimate. But I bet it takes less time than doing a rebase on all branches involved on your local, push it and then pull it everywhere. Rebase is time-consuming.

Comment: @PaulJ and what if, while you are doing your rebase on your third branch, two branches already being resolved, your boss suddenly tells you that some values are to be changed? Will you rebase your already rebased branches before continuing, or finish the rebase and to it all over again?

Comment: @PaulJ the point is that your code is so much messed up that any fixes you do now will likely need to be changed and then rebased again in the near-future. So, instead, you could tell your boss that you need to take your time to make order in your app. Also, if passwords and other secret data are being versioned inside your source-code, then you will possibly see nasty surprises. So there is security issue involved as well that you plan not to address for the time being.